# Google Image Search API: Search by two or more domain restrictions

Tags: google-api

In Google Image Search (the web interface) you can restrict your search results by a single domain. It appears that the same rule applies to the API (http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/reference.html#_methods) but as far as I know, the "one site" rule isn't documented anywhere (other than never mentioning multiple sites).

Does anyone know if it is possible to restrict a search across two or more domain names via the web interface OR the Image Search API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. The Google Image Search API is also being deprecated, so it would be best to search for alternatives anyway.